# How to fix a not existing property on a type of a component in a VueJs3 and typescript application?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, types, vuejs3

Hi I'm working on a project built with Vuejs3 and Typescript, I'm having a very simple component, a div with an image as background.

I removed from the example the css, not relevant.

```
<template>
  <div :style="style"></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: 'Imager',
  props: {
    source: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    style(): string {
      return `background-image: url('${this.source}')`
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

The code looks fine, the server has no issue, and the Vue application works perfect on the browser, but VisualStudio complains saying the following:

```
Property 'source' does not exist on type '{ style(): string; }'
```

I guess it is related to some type misconfiguration, but I can't make it work somehow. Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#defining-vue-components

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the fix:

```
interface ImagerProps {
  source: string
}

export default {
  name: 'Imager',
  props: {
    source: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    style(props: ImagerProps): string {
      return `background-image: url('${props.source}')`
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: is it possible to know the reason why the answer was downvoted? just to understand what is wrong with the answer. thanks